Where and how can I get the sourcecode of Android 2.2.3?
There is no place for a source code of Android 2.3.2, so, do you know any "hidden" websites that provide it?
I tried to search about it and asked on Reddit, but no one has it.
So, can you please help me disciver where it is?

I think this link might help. (I have not checked it, I am just think this is it).

see https://source.android.com/docs/setup/download and the corresponding "tag" section: https://source.android.com/docs/setup/reference/build-numbers#source-code-tags-and-builds, with this information you should be able to download the source code
